# Is it possible to have an InverseProperty refer to a property on a complex type

Tags: entity-framework, entity-relationship

Is it possible to have an inverseproperty refer to a property on a complex type?

This is a contrived example that shows the structure of what I want to do:

```
public class MyType {
  public MyName Name { get; set; }
}

[ComplexType]
public class MyName {
   public int ProfileId {get; set;}
   [ForeignKey("ProfileId")]
   public Profile Profile{get; set;}
}

public class Profile
{
  [InverseProperty("Name.Profile")]
   public virtual IList<MyType> MyTypes{ get;set;}
}
```

Comment: +1 for thinking outside the box. I never tried this, but in the end the complex type is just part of the entity's fields in the database, so there could be a way to resolve the path. However, I doubt whether this resolution is implemented.